# In SnowPark Python how create a table defining a schema with primary keys and foreign keys?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm building my database in SnowFlake from Python using SnowPark and I can't find how to build a table with primary and foreign keys.

I'm using the `Session.create_dataframe` method and adding a `StructType` with all my `StructField` as defined in [Create DataFrame Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/working-with-dataframes#constructing-a-dataframe). My schema:

```py
StructType([StructField('SK', IntegerType(), nullable=False), StructField('ID', IntegerType(), nullable=True), StructField('GENDER', StringType(2), nullable=True), StructField('SIGN_UP_DATE', TimestampType(), nullable=True), StructField('CITY', IntegerType(), nullable=True), StructField('COUNTRY', StringType(2), nullable=True), StructField('SIGN_UP_STORE_COUNTRY', StringType(), nullable=True), StructField('HOME_STORE_COUNTRY', StringType(2), nullable=True), StructField('ONLINE_CUSTOMER', BooleanType(), nullable=True), StructField('STORE_CUSTOMER', BooleanType(), nullable=True), StructField('HOME_STORE_COUNTRY', StringType(), nullable=True)])
```

The only problem is that I can't find where to add constraints, such as primary keys or foreign keys. Could you point me to the right examples or documentation to figure out how to do this?

Comment: You will probably need to follow the table creation with session.sql("alter table NewTable add primary key keycolumn)"